¿Cómo observar el v-model de un VAutocomplete con un whatch vue3 y typescript?
Estoy intentando hacer dinámico el atributo de items del componente VAutocomplete. Con la ayuda de un watch observo los cambios al momento que el usuario escribe algo sin embargo no se ejecuta nada, lo curioso es que al usar cualquier otro elemento de ingreso de texto y asignarle el v-model sí se ejecuta la función y se asigna el nuevo valor de los items.
Cabe mencionar que se hace una llamada de una Api cuando se ingresan más de 3 caracteres, tengo la impresión de que se debe a un problema de scope pero no estoy seguro.
Adjunto codigo:
Script
Es importante mencionar que country lo uso como auxiliar para formar el arreglo modificado.
<script setup lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios'
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const buscar = ref()
const country = ref()
const paises = ref()

interface Usuario {
  name: string
  middleName: string
  curp: string
  data: any
  headers: any
}

const resultados = () => {
  const datosBase = (async () => {
    const dataU: Usuario = await axios.post(`api/v1/geolocation/GetPlaceAsync?place=${buscar.value}`)

    country.value = dataU.data

    paises.value = country.value.map((elemento: { description: any }) => elemento.description)
  })()
}

watch(buscar, () => {
  if (buscar.value.length > 3) {
    resultados()
  }
  else {
    country.value = ''
    paises.value = ''
  }
})
</script>

La parte del Template con el componente VAutocomplete
<template>

<VAutocomplete
      v-model="buscar"
      label="States"
      density="compact"
      :items="paises"
    />

</template>

Si antes del VAutocomplete pongo lo siguiente, sí se ejecuta el watch y se modifica el arreglo de países
      <div class="contenedor">
      <VTextField
      v-model="buscar"
      label="Lugar"
      placeholder="Ingrese lugar de destino"
      />
      <ul v-if="paises">
      <li
      v-for="pais in paises"
      :key="pais"
      >
      <a href="#">{{ pais }}</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <p v-else>
      No hay datos
      </p>
      </div>

<!-- Con estilos -->

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.contenedor {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 2em;
  inline-size: 12em;
}

.contenedor > ul {
  display: block;
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-block-start: 1px solid #6bb99c;
  list-style: none;
}

.contenedor:hover > ul > li {
  padding: 5px;
  border-block-end: 1px solid #6bb99c;
}

.contenedor:hover > ul > li:hover { background: white; }
.contenedor:hover > ul > li:hover > a { color: red; }
</style>

Hay muy poca información siendo Materialize de paga lo que se emplea por lo cuál no he podido dar con el clavo, de antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda y estoy atento a sus respuestas.
Cabe mencionar que estoy iniciando en esto y a veces se me complica mucho por la cantidad limitada de información sobre el tema, agradezco mucho la comprensión, la paciencia y que hayas llegado a leer el final de mi publicación.

Vigente? solucionado?  Edito comentario para colaborar

Aún sigue vigente

El detalle esta en el tipo de componente que esta usando:
El v-combobox es un campo de texto que permite la entrada donde el valor no está en las opciones de la lista, mientras que el v-autocomplete está restringido a los elementos de la lista o items. Debió notarlo al usar el v-textfield, porque este componente sí permitió filtrar mientras escribe asignando el model(la entrada) al autocomplete.
Entendiendo eso, su script es correcto, solo modifique el template para  usar v-combobox:
<template>
  <v-combobox
    v-model="buscar"
    label="States"
    density="compact"
    :items="paises"
  />
</template>

